# How to set dynamic/variable ToolPath for Wix prebuild step (msbuild) using Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, jenkins, wix

We have a WinXP Jenkins build machine that I'm in the process of moving over to a 64bit Win-7 machine.  We are utilizing Wix to build the msi's via MSBuild..all these projects sit in TFS.  We are getting the TFS changeset number in order set to current build in each project.  The line in question in many of our [projectname].wixproj files looks like :

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsClient ToolPath="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" Command="history /stopafter:1 /version:T /format:detailed /recursive $(ProjectDir)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Changeset" PropertyName="Changeset" />
    </MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsClient>
    <Message Text="TFS ChangeSetNumber: $(Changeset)" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DefineConstants>ChangesetNumber=$(Changeset)</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

This works fine on our 32-bit machine but fails on the new 64 bit because the toolpath for TF.EXE is now in c:\Program Files (x86)...  instead of C:\program files...  I'm trying to figure out a way to make this toolpath variable so we can continue to use both build machines (for now) without dedicating the wix project file to one or the other (without breaking one of the build machines, basically).

This tf.exe toolpath is configured easily in Jenkins on a per-machine basis, but this isn't propagated down into the projects themselves...unless there's a path variables I'm unaware of?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the root tool path in a msbuild variable.
First set the default value for windows 64 bits subfolder and then depending on an environment variable set the value for 32 bits where that variable is undefined in 32 bits machine.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyProgramFiles>C:\Program Files (x86)\</MyProgramFiles>
    <MyProgramFiles Condition=" '$(CommonProgramW6432)' == '' ">C:\Program Files\</MyProgramFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So passing that variable to your .wixproj will look something like:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyProgramFiles>C:\Program Files (x86)\</MyProgramFiles>
        <MyProgramFiles Condition=" '$(CommonProgramW6432)' == '' ">C:\Program Files\</MyProgramFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsClient ToolPath="$(MyProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" Command="history /stopafter:1 /version:T /format:detailed /recursive $(ProjectDir)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Changeset" PropertyName="Changeset" />
    </MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsClient>
    <Message Text="TFS ChangeSetNumber: $(Changeset)" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefineConstants>ChangesetNumber=$(Changeset)</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

I hope this help you.